# Azure Data Factory Test Framework

Tags: automated-tests, azure-data-factory

Are there any automatic testing mechanism available for azure data factory pipelines? Does the azure data factory visual studio project come with any test suite of its own? Any help highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, but happy to be told otherwise.

I suggest you post this on Microsoft's user voice page as a feedback idea. Then people searching will come here, go to that link and vote to get something developed.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/filters/my_feedback?query=Unit%20Testing%20for%20ADF%20Projects

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Paul, will post at the link as you suggest. Will keep the question open for any inputs from other if you don't mind..

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer to avoid duplicate questions please.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT after comment:

You could use a github repository (gbrueckl - Azure.DataFactory.LocalEnvironment) for running custom pipelines local etc. His repository provides some tools which make it easier to work with Azure Data Factory (ADF). It mainly contains two features:

1. Debug Custom .Net Activities locally (within VS and without
   deployment to the ADF Service!)
2. Export existing ADF Visual Studio projects a Azure Resource Manager
   (ARM) template for deployment

   - In addition, the repository also contains various samples to
     demonstrate how to work with the ADF Local Environment.

https://github.com/gbrueckl/Azure.DataFactory.LocalEnvironment is the link to the repository for doing that. You can use it to debug your pipelines on your local environment at least and it could also help to test them...

Answer (score 0):

The only related project / sample code I'm aware of is the ability to step into and debug "DotNetActivty" outside of Azure Batch, by using your pipeline variables.

This could effectively be used as a test runner of some description.

If you have your data factory setup to be automatically deployed, you could deploy to an alternative QA environment.

Then you could probably (I haven't dug into the SDK in that area enough to know for sure) then use the SDK to run the slice and check if it ran successfully. It would be more of an integration test / end to end smoke test at this point.

[ADFCustomActivityRunner on Github](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/ADFCustomActivityRunner)