# Unit testing of Azure Data Factory

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a VSTS CI/CD pipeline that deploys the Azure Data Factory project setup in my local to the existing data factory in Azure platform. Is there a way I can unit test my project? I understand that there is a visual studio test task in build definition. How do I create a unit test project for ADF ? Any suggestions will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Data Factory Test Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386957/azure-data-factory-test-framework)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn’t Unit test for ADF project, there is a user voice that you can vote: [Unit Testing for ADF Projects](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/19511770-unit-testing-for-adf-projects)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to try to create unit test that utilizes the [ADF LocalEnvironment assembly](https://github.com/gbrueckl/Azure.DataFactory.LocalEnvironment) (instead of the Console application used in their demo try to create a Unit Test project)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "Test Plans" in Azure Devops if you are using CI/CD.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't built in unit testing in ADF, [Richard Ssinbank's example](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/unit_testing_azure_data_factory_pipelines) provides what appears to be a reasonable approach to implementing unit testing. Basically what he does is add parameters to the pipeline that allow dependency injection. The parameters start with the '_' and default to the normal dependencies that you would use in the pipeline for accessing external objects. This allows you to invoke the pipeline with stubs for testing.